# What specific changes in Android 6 and 7 that prevent ServerSocket from accepting external incoming connections

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have googled this issue for several weeks, but could not find any solution that works.

**What specific changes in Android 6 and 7 that prevent `ServerSocketfrom` accepting external incoming connections?**

For example, my Web server used to be able to do the following on Lollipop and earlier the following:

- accept connections from the browser on desktop via Wi-Fi or mobile network.
- From my PC, I used to be able to open http://192.168.254.99:8080/a.txt where 192.168.254.99 is the IP of the phone

*But now*, the same app (even after I upgraded to support Android API 23+) can not.

The problem is not specific to my app. I have downloaded several Web server apps on Google Play, and they show the same problem. Is there any fix for this problem?

My Web server is running in a service. But when I tested mine and all other Web servers, they are all running in the foreground.

Even the Google's sample app (https://developer.android.com/samples/PermissionRequest/src/com.example.android.permissionrequest/SimpleWebServer.html) has the same issue.

Comment: Do you mean `ServerSocket` is not working? I have successfully implemented messaging in LAN using `ServerSocket`. Check the source at https://github.com/nabinbhandari/android-socket-messaging

Comment: ServerSocket is working when incoming connections are "inside" the device itself. For example, a Web server app runs on an Android phone can only accepts connections from apps running within this same Android phone. ServerSocket is NOT working when incoming connections come from external sources. For example, from the desktop PC, I can not open http://192.168.254.99:8080/a.txt (assuming that the IP of the Android phone is 192.168.254.99 and the ServerSocket is listening to port 8080), and the browser will get connection timeout error.

This was not a problem on KitKat and Lollipop.

Comment: The code I provided works for two different android devices. I have also implemented it for desktop so that a desktop PC can connect to android in the same LAN just using `ServerSocket`

Comment: What you say about 6 and 7 is not observed here. ServerSocket works as good as on 5.

Comment: I built Nabin Bhandari's android-socket-messaging source. I verify that if I install app-debug.apk on Android 7, and start it as a server, then no other Android phones can connect to it. On the other hand, if I run  app-debug.apk as a server on Android 5, then every other Android phone can connect to it. I can reproduce this problem for all apps that use ServeSocket that I can get my hand on them. Definitely, Android 6 and 7 have something that prevent ServerSocket from accepting external incoming connections.